# Using wp-super-cache and amazon cloudfront - can I serve a file directly (no cdn)?

Tags: cdn, plugin-wp-supercache

I'm using the wp super cache plugin with cdn support turned on (aws cloudfront). I'm also using wp tables reloaded. The latter plugin includes a text file via ajax, and that file is being served by the cdn. The plugin doesn't do any sort of jsonp maneuvers, so the file hits access-control-allow-origin issues.

Before I go and mess with the plugin to pull the file correctly, does anyone know how I can restrict the cdn from storing this file, and just serve it up directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDN tab of wp-supercache allows you to exclude files and folders.

[edited to add]

The field `exclude if substring` allows entry of a comma separated set of strings (eg `.php, wp-include, specialpluginjsfilename`). Any file names that match against this set of values is excluded from the CDN.

So, using the example above the following would be excluded from the CDN

- All .php files
- Any files or any file from any directory that has the string `wp-include` in it
- Any file or any file from any directory that has the string `specialpluginjsfilename` in it.

Comment: This? https://skitch.com/hookedonwinter/ermt9/wp-super-cache-denver-off-the-wagon-wordpress -- help text wasn't very clear on the tab